# Vichuploader Bundle And Background-image

Tags: vichuploaderbundle, symfony6

I am using Vichuploader to upload the photos of a category, the problem is that I need to retrieve the image from the css . Background-image and I don't know how to implement the code here.

**{{asset ('images/services/')}}{{category.image}}** for html template but css ??
style="background-image:url(***images/services/image.jpg***);"

Help me please.!
[image]

I am trying this suggestion :

```
 <div class="row">
        {% for  category in categories %}
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 ftco-animate">
            <div class="block-7">
                <div class="img prix"
                 style="background-image: url('{{ 
           vich_uploader_asset(category, 'image') }}')">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
</div>
```

but i have this error :
[image]

My Html have this error too:
[image]

My Code :
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `vich_uploader_asset()` in a twig file to generate the url for your image:

```html
<div class="img prix" 
     style="background-image: url('{{ vich_uploader_asset(category, 'imageFile') }}')"
></div>
```

This twig function is [documented here](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/docs/generating_urls.md#generating-a-url-in-a-twig-template)

Comment: tahnks you,  but I still have an error

Comment: Replace `'image'` with `'imageFile'` inside `vich_uploader_asset`

Comment: Or if you have only one single mapped field you can remove the second parameter (`'imageFile'`): `{{ vich_uploader_asset(category) }}`